# 413: Request Entity Too Large on HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, https

I've seen several questions with the same problem and most propose the following solutions

1. increse the `post_max_size` in the `php.ini` file (set to 8M)
2. increse `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` file (set to 8M)
3. set the `LimitRequestBody` directive in `httpd.conf` (set to 8388608 = 8M)

#### none of them worked for me!

Then I restarted the apache service but even still the same problem. the form I am trying to send has only 5 fields (two checkboxes, 2 selects, one file), I'm uploading a file of 653KB and dont work (work if the file is less 80K), never had this problem before.

Setup:

- ArchLinux
- x86_64 Linux 3.10.6-2-ARCH
- PHP 5.4.18
- Apache/2.2.25
- Virtual host with SSL enabled

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that the problem is when I have SSL enabled, it has a default configuration `SSLRenegBufferSize` in `131072` (128k).

Adding this directive in the virtual host directory I can increase the size and the error no longer appears:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   # ...
   <Directory ...>
        #...
        SSLRenegBufferSize 8388608 # 8M
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

add only

SSLRenegBufferSize 8388608
(without # 8M )

Comment: I have this exact problem as well. Can you please specify where to locate this virtual host directory?